# 'Please adjust your type hint accordingly' error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I try to deploy my symfony2 project using capifony.

Howevere while updating process, this error happens.

> Deprecation Notice: 
>   The callback `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap`
>   declared at
>   /var/www/html/wisdom/shared/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php
>   accepts a `Composer\Script\CommandEvent` but post-install-cmd events use
>   a `Composer\Script\Event` instance. Please adjust your type hint
>   accordingly, see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-classes in
>   phar:///var/www/html/wisdom/releases/20170107180608/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:311

---

Thanks to @robske_110
This event is found to be related with composer version.

In Local environment

> You are already using composer version 1.3.1 (stable channel)

while deploying, updating composer failed.

```
  * executing "sh -c 'cd /var/www/html/wisdom/releases/20170107183509 && php composer.phar self-update '"
    servers: ["wisdom-my.com"]
    [wisdom-my.com] executing command
 ** [out :: wisdom-my.com] Updating to version 1.3.1 (stable channel).
*** [err :: wisdom-my.com] Downloading: Connecting...
*** [err :: wisdom-my.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom-my.com] Downloading: 100%
*** [err :: wisdom-my.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom-my.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom-my.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom-my.com] Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 8ad6385ffb68495e1d2afc8c554526d018e2d8e9
```

Comment: I can't see the error you mention. The output looks completely fine when updating Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the method typehint in the file

```
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap declared at /var/www/html/wisdom/shared/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php
```

from Composer\Script\CommandEvent (or just CommandEvent, in that case there should be a use statement at the top, you need to modify that too.) to Composer\Script\Event (or Event).

But this indicates an incompatibility between your Distrubution Bundle and the Composer version, so try updating both to their latest version.

Comment: Thanks very much!!  My compoer version is latest `You are already using composer version 1.3.1 (stable channel).` however while deploying , `** [out :: wisdom.com] Updating to version 1.3.1 (stable channel).
*** [err :: wisdom.com] Downloading: Connecting...
*** [err :: wisdom.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom.com] Downloading: 100%
*** [err :: wisdom.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom.com] 
*** [err :: wisdom.com] Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 8ad6385ffb68495e1d2afc8c554526d018e2d8e9`

Comment: Finally I have roll backed the version to 4.0~~.   `"sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~4.0",` .Maybe it is because of version5 error.